# Oracle Autodop disabled at the table level

Tags: oracle, performance, parallelism, query-performance

I have a question related to Oracle auto DOP and parallel DML concepts. I have a scenario, if  I set the Auto DOP set to 1 on the table and if I run parallel DML statements on that table through parallel hint, will the query processing happens in parallel execution or since the Auto dop is set to 1 will it be a serial execution?

Can you please provide some insight on this topic.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have "Auto DOP set to 1". You can either have:
- have auto DOP, meaning Oracle will attempt to automatically determine optimal DOP
- set DOP to 1, for example with `ALTER TABLE PARALLEL 1`

The second option disables parallel query, so yes, query will execute serially. Unless you override it with a hint or `ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL QUERY`.